# Do out-of-combat spells use spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, spell-slots, non-combat

This feels like a dumb question, but does casting spells out of combat (like if someone used *detect magic*) use up spell slots? I would assume it does but I wanted to check in case.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Stack. I recommend the [tour] to get yourself oriented. Happy stacking!

Comment: is there anything that makes you think they wouldn't?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Yes, they do.**

As described in the [basic rules for spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#SpellSlots):

> When a character casts a spell, he or she expends a slot of that spell's level or higher, effectively "filling" a slot with the spell.

There are no exceptions noted here about being in or out of combat.

However, some spells in 5th edition can be [cast as a ritual](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Rituals), in which case it takes an extra 10 minutes to cast but doesn't use the spell slot. For example, *identify* normally takes 1 minute to cast, but if you spend 11 minutes it doesn't use a spell slot.

*Detect magic* normally takes 1 action (6 seconds) but it can also be cast as a ritual. It takes 10 minutes and 6 seconds to cast, but then you don't use the spell slot.

Note that not all spellcasters can cast spells as a ritual, only those with the Ritual Casting feature. There are also some other sources for ritual casting, such as the warlock's Book of Ancient Secrets eldritch invocation and the Ritual Caster feat.

Comment: Caveat emptor: not all classes that can cast these spells can do so as a ritual, so always check the label.

Comment: It looks like the question had the [dnd-5e] tag when it was asked, so it's not clear why you're unsure about what game the asker is playing.

Comment: @V2Blast Maybe I missed it, but I didn't see a tag for edition when I started working on the answer hence the initial caveat. It may have been added between when I started typing and posted my answer, and of course it's also possible I just didn't see it.

Comment: @aslum: It's possible that the tag was edited in during the "grace period" – though I believe that since the asker is a new user, they wouldn't have had the [10 reputation needed to make edits during that "grace period" without it appearing as a separate entry in the revision history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user).

Comment: Some suggestions for improvement: (1) Link to the [Ritual](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Rituals) rules and /or quote the section that says the difference is that ritual spells don't cost slots, (2) Link to the [Spell Slots](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#SpellSlots) rules, which say that a slot is used, don't give any exceptions outside of combat, but do list a few exceptions, and (3) mention that ritual casts still require the spell to be prepared (for non-wizards) or for the spellbook to be on hand (for wizards).

Comment: Maybe a better first liner would be *Yes, except when they don't* or *sometimes*. All the * touched/initiate feats grant a free use of a spell 1/LR, for example. Many races have spells that don't use slots 1/LR.

Comment: @Wyrmwood: Those feats would also apply to in-combat casting, so I think a simple yes is a good start, because being in or out of combat / initiative alone doesn't change things.  Possible phrasing to draw attention to the possibility of exceptions: "Yes, unless you have a special way to cast it without a spell slot."  i.e. that not using a spell slot would happen because you chose to cast it differently, not anything automatic because you aren't in combat.  That would also cover specific rules like 1/LR no-slot casts from feats or eldritch invocations.

Comment: @KirtnoQA4mewhilemodsstrike: There are probably some existing canonical Q&As about ritual casting which this answer should just link instead being a whole self-contained guide.  The specific question of whether casting is different just because you aren't in combat is a simple no, so just a pointer to further information is fine.

Comment: @Wyrmwood I think mentioning ritual casting but not freely granted spells is good here because ritual casting was created specifically as a way to cast (some) spells out-of-combat without it costing you spell slots.

Comment: You should also mention that spell components, like the 100 gp pearl for Identify, do still get consumed when the spell is cast as a ritual.

Comment: @Zibbobz Why would I mention something that isn't true? Identify doesn't consume it's components ritual or not

Comment: @aslum Oh...for some reason I thought it did, that's my mistake.

Comment: @Zibbobz: There are some ritual spells with material components that are consumed on cast, like Find Familiar, Protection from Evil & Good, Augury and some other divination spells, and some others.  Including Fortune's Favor which does consume a 100 gp pearl.  (In 5e the default is that materials aren't consumed.  Apparently in previous editions, materials were consumed unless it specified they weren't.)

Comment: @PeterCordes And in even _earlier_ editions, material components either were or weren't consumed, as defined in the spell descriptions. The default behaviour or material components is something that's changed a lot over time.